# Logic behind lazy regex using '?'?

Tags: regex, lazy-evaluation, greedy, regex-greedy, non-greedy

here is my question:

For example if your pattern is:

**abc?**

Then this will match:
**ab
abc**
but not **abd**
as c? means: if there is a c, match, if not, no worries..

So say you have something like this:

**->sometext<-->somemoretext<-**

if you have a pattern like this: ( which is greedy ) 
**->.*<-** then it will only match:

**->sometext<-->sometext<-**

however if your pattern is lazy:
**->.*?<-** then it will match: 
**->sometext<**- AND **->sometext<-**...

If, ? means, something like wheter/not ( as in the first example ), then what is the logic behind the second example, can someone explain? 
Why does it stop in ->sometext-< if the pattern is .*?

Comment: Do you mean, why does `?` have more than one meaning, depending on context?

Comment: So it does have more then one meaning? I really did not know that, and I was trying to understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

? when placed after a * or + or ? makes it lazy. As in, it will try to match 0 characters, then 1 character if that failed, then 2 if that failed... as opposed to matching MAX characters, then MAX-1 if that failed, then MAX-2 if that failed... which is the behaviour by default - 'greedy' and wanting to match as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the logic.

Answer (score 2):

`?` means different things in different contexts.

In fact, `c??` is a valid expression - it says match 'c' only if you must.

The question mark actually has more than two meanings. For example:

- [zero-width lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?=.*)`.
- [atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html): `(?>.*)`
- [named grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html): `(?<NAME>.*)`
- and many, many more...

Answer (score 1):

When used in this context:

`abc?`

Then you are matching a, b and c if it exists.  When used in this context:

`->.*?<-`

Then you are matching `->` followed by and including everything up to the first occurrence of `<-`.  As opposed to:

`->.*<-`

Which would just mean to match `->` followed by an optional, infinite number of any character, plus `<-`.  In this case of course, the `.*` would gobble up `<-`.

Comment: Interesting thanks. What if I want to say something like this: Match from -> to first occurrence of <- and in between match ab AND c if it exists?

Comment: So for this case, you would want to match `->abc<-` but not `->123abc456<-`?

Comment: my text is: ->ab<-->abc<->-abd-< I do not want to make it greedy(as it is too easy and I think I got it already), I want to match the first two ->ab<- and ->abc<- but using the c? in regex ( to understand it. )

Comment: @KorayTugay - You need to ask this in your question if you want it answered (so that everyone has an opportunity to provide an answer)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I am afraid it might get closed because it is too localized.

Comment: @KorayTugay - then generalize your question. The goal, afterall, is to learn something, not have someone do the coding *for* you.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I really do not have any coding right now to do. I am just trying to learn Regex. It will be a good example for me to understand. It is ok, nevermind. Thanks.